# woocommerce recent product hover color

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, hover

I am working with shopisle theme and Fusion builder (avada). I introduced the recent product short code on my home page and was abel to round the pictures and change the button colors form black to blue with white letters. When you mouseover there is white box round the blue button. I want that just to be transparent with the blue button on hover. If theres a way to get the Black small box (¡oferta!) red that would be awesome. Google did not help me to find the solution. I hope anyone here can help me. THX in advance.

Best regards Jordi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to remove `background` here:

```
.product:not(.elementor):hover .prod-img-wrap:before, .shop-item:hover .prod-img-wrap:before, .prod-img-wrap:hover:before {

    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);

}
```

and add the transparency code to the image:

```
.prod-img-wrap:hover img {

    opacity: 0.6;

}
```

Comment: that worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. may be you have a solution for the small black box as well. Red with white letters would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

I got the sale badge working by adding this code to custom css

```
.woocommerce span.onsale{
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
```